# ExtJS 4.0.7 fieldcontainer vbox layout

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am trying to make one form in "extjs" in which i want to use "vbox layout" so that i can place textfield and a button in the same line but unable to do that please help me as early as possible please ???

This is the following code which i am using to create a form:

```
[{ formitems :{[xtype:'dsqfieldcontainer'
                layout: {
                           type: 'vbox'
                        },
               items:[{mapping:'ChannelURL',
                       name:'ChannelURL',
                       fieldLabel:'Channel URL',
                       xtype:'dsqtextfield'
                      },
                      {mapping:'Look_Up_ChannelID',
                        name:'Look_Up_ChannelID',
                        fieldLabel:'Look_Up_ChannelID',
                        xtype:dsqbutton
                       }
                      ]
                 ] },
                   {
                     mapping:'CHANNELNAME',
                     name:'CHANNELNAME',
                     fieldLabel:'Channel Name',
                     xtype:'dsqtextfield'
                    },
                    {
                      mapping:'CHANNELID',
                      name:'CHANNELID',
                      fieldLabel:'Channel ID',
                      xtype:'dsqtextfield'
                    },
                    {
                      mapping:'REFRESHTOKEN',
                      name:'REFRESHTOKEN',
                      fieldLabel:'Refresh Token',
                      xtype:'dsqtextfield'
                    }
 }]
```

Comment: Please format your form code properly.  Thanks.

Comment: Give us complete code here  - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home. Indentation is not good of your coding.. Only first 2 items will come vertically 'dsqtextfield' & 'dsqbutton'. There are many syntax problem also in coding.

Comment: i have added my complete code in the site provided by you Puneet can you help me know

Comment: Hi @AnvitaTiwari. Then give me a link where you have saved so that i can find issue. You have to create a account on that site and after that it will be permanently saved. When you save copy the URL and paste here or share it where you want to.

Comment: sorry @PuneetChawla i forgot to give you link , this is the link where you can get my code https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rhd

Comment: @AnvitaTiwari - I have posted answer. Check it and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check below code and you will get your mistake. In my code, textbox and button are showing in one line by hbox layout. Just check it and let me know if you get any issue. My fiddler account is not working. That's why i can't give you link.

My example -

```
 Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype:'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items:[{
                       mapping:'ChannelURL',
                       name:'ChannelURL',
                       fieldLabel:'Channel URL',
                       xtype:'textfield'
                    },
                    {
                        mapping:'Look_Up_ChannelID',
                        name:'Look_Up_ChannelID',
                        xtype:'button',
                       text: 'Button Name'
                    }]
                }]
        }).show();
```

[image]

Changes in your example -

```
items:[
                    {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        mapping: 'ChannelURL',
                        name: 'ChannelURL',
                        fieldLabel: 'Channel URL',
                        xtype: 'textfield'
                    }, {
                        mapping: 'Look_Up_ChannelID',
                        name: 'Look_Up_ChannelID',
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Button Name'
                    }]
                    },
                    {
                        mapping: 'CHANNELNAME',
                        name: 'CHANNELNAME',
                        fieldLabel: 'Channel Name',
                        xtype: 'textfield'
                    }, {
                        mapping: 'CHANNELID',
                        name: 'CHANNELID',
                        fieldLabel: 'Channel ID',
                        xtype: 'textfield'
                    }, {
                        mapping: 'REFRESHTOKEN',
                        name: 'REFRESHTOKEN',
                        fieldLabel: 'Refresh Token',
                        xtype: 'textfield'
                    }
                ]
```

[image]

Comment: HI @Puneet after doing the changes still i am getting an error in tomcate "expected ',' or ']' at character 12 .. this is the link of my code please let me know https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rhf

Comment: @AnvitaTiwari - I have updated my answer and did changes in your example and just copy my code and add in your program.. you just need to add from items and change xtype.. It will work surely now. Please check your brackets again.

Comment: @AnvitaTiwari - I hope, issue has been solved. If still not then let me know.

Comment: @AnvitaTiwari - Okay. Then you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
layout: {
    type: 'table'
}
```